# Manipulate starts to recalculate infinitely

Tags: manipulate

I'm fitting data inside Manipulate and it works good

```
model = Evaluate[H1*complex[r, k1, 1]];
fitRes = FindFit[data, model, {H1, k1}, r, Method -> "NMinimize"];
```

but when I'm trying to create the function with found parameters `fitted[r_] := model /. fitRes;` to plot found fit the Manipulate starts to recalculate infinitely. Why it happens and how to avoid it?

Here is the working example:

```
n = 2;
Quiet[solution = Solve[{K*P*M == PM, P0 == P + PM, r*P0 == M + PM}, {P, M, PM}]];
vala = PM /. Take[solution, {n, n}];

complex[rVal_, KVal_, P0Val_, DifInd_: 0] := Re@With[{r = rVal, K = KVal, P0 = P0Val,índex = DifInd}, (Evaluate@D[vala, {r, índex}])];

rmin = 0.1;
Manipulate[
 data = Table[Evaluate[{r, H*complex[r, k, 10^p0, 1][[1]]}], {r, rmin, rmax, 0.1}];
 rnd = Table[{0, RandomReal[{-ee, ee}]}, {r, rmin, rmax, 0.1}];
model = Evaluate[H1*complex[r, k1, 10^p0, 1]];
fitRes = FindFit[data + rnd, model, {H1, k1}, r, Method -> "NMinimize"];
fitted[r_] = model /. fitRes;
Row[{Show[{ListPlot[data + rnd, PlotMarkers -> 
   Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 10]]}]}], 
  {{rmax,2, "r"}, 1, 10}, 
  {{k, 1000001, "k"}, 10001, 10000001}, 
  {{p0, -3.5, "10^P0"}, -1, -10}, Delimiter, 
  {{H, -100,"H"}, -300, 300}, 
  {{ee, 0.0015, "Error"}, -0.1, 0.1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal self-contained working example.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I did it

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков I think that "***minimal***" is the important key in the previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to stick the extra variables `data`, `rnd`, etc. into a `Module`.  Another way is to use `TrackedSymbols`.  I'll show the second way, in case using global variables was intentional.

The easiest way is to use the setting `TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate`, which tracks only the variables declared in `Manipulate`.  One other change was needed.  Setting `PerformanceGoal` is needed to prevent an update when a slider is first dragged and then let go.  After it is let go. [`$ControlActiveSetting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ControlActiveSetting.html) changes from `True` to `False`.

By default, `PerformanceGoal` is set to [`$PerformanceGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PerformanceGoal.html), which is by default set to `ControlActive["Speed","Quality"]`.  This means that when `$ControlActiveSetting` changes, the `ListPlot`, which depends on it through `PerformanceGoal`, causes the `Manipulate` to update one more time, causing a new random sample to be generated.

```
Manipulate[
 data = Table[
   Evaluate[{r, H*complex[r, k, 10^p0, 1][[1]]}], {r, rmin, rmax, 
    0.1}];
 rnd = Table[{0, RandomReal[{-ee, ee}]}, {r, rmin, rmax, 0.1}];
 model = Evaluate[H1*complex[r, k1, 10^p0, 1]];
 fitRes = 
  FindFit[data + rnd, model, {H1, k1}, r, Method -> "NMinimize"];
 fitted[r_] = model /. fitRes;
 Row[{Show[{ListPlot[data + rnd, 
      PlotMarkers -> 
       Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 10], 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]}]}], {{rmax, 2, "r"}, 1, 
  10}, {{k, 1000001, "k"}, 10001, 
  10000001}, {{p0, -3.5, "10^P0"}, -1, -10}, Delimiter, {{H, -100, 
   "H"}, -300, 300}, {{ee, 0.0015, "Error"}, -0.1, 0.1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate]
```