# I don't know why the data get refreshed when I push a button

Tags: manipulate

I have an app that creates random data and represents them. It has a button that allows download the data. But I don't know why the data get refreshed when I push the button that I have created to download the data. As the data get refreshed before I push the button, the data downloaded don't match with the new data I can see in the display. However, if I remove the code that creates the graph, the behavior of the application is different because when I push the button, the data don't get updated. Thank you in advance.

```
color1 = RGBColor[206/255, 170/255, 105/255];(* Naranja *)
color2 = 
 RGBColor[182/255, 195/255, 135/255];(* Verde *)
color3 = 
 RGBColor[103/255, 151/255, 190/255];(* Azul *)
dotmarker = 
 Graphics[{color1, Disk[]}];
sizedotmarkermin = 0.031;(*Para fijar el tamaño mínimo de los puntos \
representados en el dartboard*)
sizedotmarkermax = 0.06;
(* \[Mu]=50 (* valor de la media *); *)
(* \[Sigma]=10 (*valor de la \
desviación típica*); *)
nmin = 8 (* tamaño mínimo de las muestras *);
nmax = 14(* tamaño máximo de las muestras *);
m = 16 (* número de muestras *);
(* Repeticiones = 35(* Número de repeticiones del Bucle *); *)

Opa = 0.2 (* Opacidad de los rectángulos delimitadores de la \
variabilidad*);
NAleat1 = 
  RandomInteger[{1, 
    m/2}] (* Para determinar cuál será la primer muestra *);
NAleat2 = 
  RandomInteger[{m/2, 
    m}] (* Para determinar cuál será la segunda muestra *);
NAleat3 = 
  RandomInteger[{1, 
    m}] (* Para determinar cuál será la tercera muestra *);

Manipulate[ClearAll;
 r;(* Para crear un botón de refresco cuando se modifique \[Mu] o \
\[Sigma] *)
 (* Para determinar el color de los puntos *)

 sizedotmarker = (5 - Repeticiones)*sizedotmarkermin/(1000 - 5) + 
   sizedotmarkermax; (* Para que el tamaño de los puntos \
representados esté en función del número de observaciones *)

 Do[
  For[i = 1, i < m + 1, i++, 
   Muestra[i] = 
    Round[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
      RandomInteger[{nmin, nmax}]]]];
  Datos = Table[Muestra[i], {i, m}];
  CabeceraColum = Table["Cliente " <> TextString[k], {k, nmax}];
  CabeceraFil = Table["Muestra " <> TextString[l], {l, m}];

  (* Asignación del valor de los estadísticos *)

  Estadistico1[q] = N@Mean[Muestra[1]];


  , {q, Repeticiones}];

 valorminest1 = 
  Min[Table[
    Estadistico1[i], {i, 
     Repeticiones}]];(* Para calcular el valor mínimo de los valores \
del estadistico 1 calculados para cada muestra *)

 valormaxest1 = Max[Table[Estadistico1[i], {i, Repeticiones}]];

 CabeResFil = Table["Mes " <> TextString[k], {k, Repeticiones}];
 CabeResColum = Table["Estadístico " <> TextString[k], {k, 4}];
 Est = Table[{Estadistico1[i], Estadistico2[i], Estadistico3[i], 
    Estadistico4[i]}, {i, Repeticiones}];

 (* Quitar este comentario para que se visualice la tabla resumen de \
valor de estadísticos en cada muestra 
 Print[TableForm[Est,TableHeadings\[Rule]{CabeResFil,CabeResColum \
},TableAlignments\[Rule]Center]]; *)

 EspEst = 
  Mean[Table[{Estadistico1[i], Estadistico2[i], Estadistico3[i], 
     Estadistico4[i]}, {i, 
     Repeticiones}]](* Para calcular la esperanza del estimador *);
 VarEst = 
  Variance[Table[{Estadistico1[i], Estadistico2[i], Estadistico3[i], 
     Estadistico4[i]}, {i, 
     Repeticiones}]](* Para calcular la varianza del estimador *);
 ECMEst = 
  VarEst + (EspEst - \[Mu])^2(* Para calcular el Error Cuadrático \
Medio del estimador *);

 PosicionECMMin = 
  Position[ECMEst, Min[ECMEst]] [[1, 
   1]];(* Para determinar la posición en la lista que ocupa el \
estadístico con menor ECM*)

 (* Para crear una lista de pares de valores compuesta por el valor \
de los estadísticos y un valor adicional que sirva para representarlo \
en el dartboard *)

 DataDartBoard = 
  Table[Table[{Est[[i, q]], 
     RandomVariate[
      NormalDistribution[EspEst[[q]], Sqrt[ECMEst[[q]]]]]}, {i, 
     Repeticiones}], {q, 4}];

 (* Extrae el primer valor de la primera tabla de pares de valores de \
estadísticos y coord 'y' FUNCIONA *) 
 MinDataDartBoardCoordX = 
  Min[Table[{DataDartBoard[[q, i, 1]]}, {i, Repeticiones}, {q, 
     4}]];(* Extrae el menor valor de la coordenada X del par de \
datos contenido en DataDartBoard *)

 MaxDataDartBoardCoordX = 
  Max[Table[{DataDartBoard[[q, i, 1]]}, {i, Repeticiones}, {q, 4}]];
 MinDataDartBoardCoordY = 
  Min[Table[{DataDartBoard[[q, i, 2]]}, {i, Repeticiones}, {q, 4}]];
 MaxDataDartBoardCoordY = 
  Max[Table[{DataDartBoard[[q, i, 2]]}, {i, Repeticiones}, {q, 4}]];


 Column[{Table[{Estadistico1[i]}, {i, Repeticiones}], Show[
    Graphics[{Thickness[0.1], color3, Opacity[1], 
      Circle[{\[Mu], \[Mu]}, 
       1.2*Max[Abs[MaxDataDartBoardCoordX - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MaxDataDartBoardCoordY - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MinDataDartBoardCoordX - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MinDataDartBoardCoordY - \[Mu]]]], 
      Circle[{\[Mu], \[Mu]}, 
       1.2*0.5*Max[Abs[MaxDataDartBoardCoordX - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MaxDataDartBoardCoordY - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MinDataDartBoardCoordX - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MinDataDartBoardCoordY - \[Mu]]]], 
      Circle[{\[Mu], \[Mu]}, 
       1.2*0.01 Max[Abs[MaxDataDartBoardCoordX - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MaxDataDartBoardCoordY - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MinDataDartBoardCoordX - \[Mu]], 
         Abs[MinDataDartBoardCoordY - \[Mu]]]]}, 
     AxesLabel -> {None, 
       " \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(1\)]\) = \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)], \(n\)]\)
       "}],
    ListPlot[DataDartBoard[[1]], 
     PlotMarkers -> {dotmarker, sizedotmarker}], Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {\[Mu], \[Mu]}],
   " ", Button["Download data", 
    Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "Data.xls"], Est], 
    Method -> "Queued", ImageSize -> 150, Background -> color1]}]


   , Column[{Style["Distribution Normal parameters", Bold, Medium], 
   Spacer[20], 
   Row[{Control[{\[Mu], 50}], Spacer[20], Control[{\[Sigma], 10}], 
     Spacer[20], Control[{{r, True}, None}], 
     Button["Refresh", r = ! r], "", 
     Control[{{Repeticiones, 50, "Repetitions (from 5 to 1000)"}, 5, 
       1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}]}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Top, ContinuousAction -> False, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {Repeticiones, r}]
```

Comment: [Minimal Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example).

Comment: And, despite the need for an MWE, your code - as provided - doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96899/manipulate-starts-to-recalculate-infinitely/96936#96936

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica recalculates the random number every time it is used, that is , including your download part. To avoid getting results like this, try `BlockRandom` to hold the numbers. Or if you want a specific list of random, use `RandomSeed`

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem because into my app, I use the "manipulate" command and it is important to generate new random samples each time a push a button. The matter is that the app shows a set of data and there is a button to download these data but every time a push the download button, the data get refreshed and the download data don't match with the new data the user can see in the screen. Is there any way to set the data showed in order to get the data downloaded be the same that the data displayed? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Pcouper Of course you can! You can set a temporary variable to store the data